# Parse SQL queries with python

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, sqlite, parsing

My question is a little about python but mostly about algorithms.

I am currently working on a Python parser for SQLite queries especially the INSERT query. The parser will have to recognize the table for the query and isolate each new value.

But I have an issue with recognizing the values in a column which can be filled with one of two methods :

```
insert into WeirdTable ("PARAMETERS","NAME","VALUE") VALUES (NULL,"BOB","0965");
insert into WeirdTable ("PARAMETERS","NAME","VALUE") VALUES ("Param1,Param2,Param3","Joe","00859");
insert into WeirdTable ("PARAMETERS","NAME","VALUE") VALUES ("Param1,Param2,Param3,Param4","Jack","00855");
insert into WeirdTable ("PARAMETERS","NAME","VALUE") VALUES ("Param1","Bill","00159");
```

the parameters column can take either : NULL or "Param1,Param2,....."

I first based my parsing on the number of commas inside the second set of brackets but since the number of parameters can change it corrupts the way I coded it. I also tried to use the number of quotes but since there can be NULL for parameters it didn't work either.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank a lot

Edit :

Here is my code

```
def smartReader(text):
    if text.count("(")==2 and text.count(")")==2 :
        temp = text[findnth(text, "(", 0)+1:findnth(text, ")", 0)]
        print 'between first parentehses : ' , temp
        nb_param = temp.count("\"")/2
        print 'number of parametters ' , nb_param 
        param_list=[]
        l=0
        for param in range(1,2*nb_param,2):
            param_list.append(temp[findnth(temp, "\"", param-1)+1 : findnth(temp, "\"", param)])
            print 'parameter inserted : ' ,param_list[l]
            l+=1
    return param_list
```

What I want to do with this code is that I have files with different types of insert either with mentionning the values :

```
insert into WeirdTable ("PARAMETERS","NAME","VALUE") VALUES (NULL,"BOB","0965");
```

or directly

```
insert into WeirdTable VALUES (NULL,"BOB","0965");
```

so for that I check the number of parenthesys and then inside each parenthesis I have to find the number of parameters

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel : https://sqlparse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/

Comment: How do you handle commas inside strings? Comments? Computed values? Subqueries? Common table expressions?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is actually an assignment where I cant use an external module such as sqlparser. Any other ideas ? I tried to look at the source code for the sqlparser but I didnt grasp what they were doing. Thanks again, regards

Comment: @CL : I didn't understand your question, could please develop ? thanks for your interest in my question.

Comment: Well, if it's an assignment, then you are probably not required to parse everything that SQLite supports.

Comment: What would you need the number of commas or quotes for? Show your code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, sorry i couldnt explain more what I was doing : I modified the origanl question to include my code

Comment: It is often required to show some code to prove you made some research. But others really need *specification* of what you need exactly: what is format of possible input (fixed and variable parts), what controls are needed on it and what shall be produced?

Comment: Hello  Serge Ballesta, what I need to do is simply to parse any given INSERT query without knowing the number of arguments or the type of the syntax used. I managed to do that but I am stuck when an argument show onlu NULL without any quotes (I am based on those to claculate the number of arguments) also if I base my algorithm on commas in the text I am stuck with some kind of arguments that have commas inside them